# Consuming jsonp with angularjs, (can't CORS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, jsonp

I have to load a JSON file from another server (where I don't have control). After some hours researching found that JSONP is the dirty hack that answers mine pleads.

I am using nodejs, serving the site on localhost:3000 using gulp.
Loading the JSON from localhost:8000

I was able to get an example working, from an URL I do not need (found it randomly on the Internet), using the same code that I had not working with my URL.

That makes me wonder if I am trying to read the file like something it is not? As far as I could research it shouldn't be needed to parse a JSON into JSONP. Am I on the right track?

Underneath, the code which I was talking about:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('qwe.asd')
    .controller('UsersController', UsersController);

/** @ngInject */
function UsersController($http, $log, $sce) {

    var vm = this;
    var trustedUsersAPI = "http://localhost:8000/users?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(trustedUsersAPI);

    $http.jsonp(trustedUsersAPI, {
            'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $log.log("request 1 - OK");
            $log.log(data);
            vm.users = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $log.log("request 1 - KO");
        });

    var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

    $http.jsonp(url)
        .success(function (data) {
            $log.log("request 2 - OK");
            $log.log(data);
        })
        .error(function () {
            $log.log("request 2 - KO");
        });


}
})();
```

And the logs generated...

```
angular.js:13424 request 1 - KO
angular.js:13424 request 2 - OK
angular.js:13424 Object {found: 12, posts: Array[12]}
```

And finally, the JSON files I am (mis)reading:

The one I need but I can't have

```
[{"id":0,"firstname":"front","lastname":"end","email":"frontend@example.com"},{"id":1,"firstname":"back","lastname":"end","email":"backend@example.com"},{"id":2,"firstname":"john","lastname":"doe","email":"johndoe@example.com"},{"id":3,"firstname":"dev","lastname":"eloper","email":"developer@example.com"},{"id":4,"firstname":"ad","lastname":"min","email":"admin@example.com"}]
```

And the one I don't need but works fine

```
{"found":12,"posts":[{"ID":XX,"site_ID":XXXX,"author":XXXX(..POSTS DATA WITH NO VALUE HERE..)}]}
```

P.S. I am really green here, I am on angular since this morning!

Comment: so... what is working and isn't working?

Comment: *"After some hours researching found that JSONP is the dirty hack that answers mine pleads."* Only if that server supports JSONP. What the server sends back for JSON vs. JSONP is **different**. JSON example: `{"foo":"bar"}` JSONP example: `callback({"foo":"bar"})`

Comment: The JSON contained in trustedUsersAPI is accessible through the network tab (on Chrome's devtools) but somehow isn't reachable through the code. @KevinB

Comment: I thought that callback is generated automatically from the parameter JSON_CALLBACK? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @ManuelGarridoGutierrez automatically, by the server, yeah. ***If** the server supports JSONP*.

Comment: @ManuelGarridoGutierrez — Your client library will generate the client side of it automatically. If, and only if, the server *supports JSONP*, the server generate the server side of it in response.

Comment: To use JSONP, the server must support JSONP. Just like the server needs to support CORS to be able to use CORS.

Comment: Thanks @all, got a solid understanding of it now ;)

Answer (score -1):

For those who come after me, I was following the wrong track. Thanks to the commenters I learnt that JSONP has to be supported on the server (just like CORS does).